# VueJs component using CDN link without npm

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Want to use [Laravel Vue Pagination](https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>
<pagination :data="users" @pagination-change-page="getUsers"></pagination>
```

**Vue/Js**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/laravel-vue-pagination@2.3.1/dist/laravel-vue-pagination.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        users: [],       
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getUsers();
    },
    methods: {
        getThoughts(page = 1) {
            axios.get('/api/users?page=' + page)
                .then(response => {
                    this.users = response.data;
                });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

**Problem:**
Loop is working fine when using the pagination component gives me the following error.

**Error**

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <pagination> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

**Tried**

```
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));
```

Gives me following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading a component using UMD modules. When loading a UMD module through script tag, the module gets added to the window object. You can access it using `window['module-name']`. Then you need to register the component in Vue object just like u would do it normally.

In your case you need to add:

```
      components: {
        pagination: window['laravel-vue-pagination']
      },
```

to your Vue component so umd module laravel-vue-pagination will be registered and ready to use inside template.